# Site not displaying properly on ipad and iphone. header and footer in place, body/container not

Tags: css, ipad, wordpress

My site is http://farmersforum.in which is not displaying properly on ipad and iphone. The header and footer and left aligned but the body is right aligned and starts from where the header ends.

the #container width is 1020px so i dont think that is the problem. Here's the css code;

```
/*  
Theme Name: gazpoMag
Theme URI: gazpo.com
Description: gazpoMag is a clean and featured-rich Wordpress magazine style theme. It allows you to easily customize every detail of the theme to best suit your needs. 
Author: Sami Ch.
Author URI: http://www.gazpo.com
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt

*/
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body{
    color: #333333; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #004A8D;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #004A8D;
}

a { outline: none;  }

h2, h3, h4{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

h2{ 
    font-size:16px; 
    margin:10px 0 3px; 
}

h3{
    font-size: 16px;
}

h4{
    font-size: 16px;
}

h2 a,  h2 a:visited{
    color:#004A8D;
    font-size:16px; 
}

h2 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#133451;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

img.centered {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    }

img.alignright {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 0 2px 7px;
    display: inline;
    }

img.alignleft {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 7px 2px 0;
    display: inline;
    }

.alignright {
    float: right;
    }

.alignleft {
    float: left;
    }

#container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1020px;
    text-align: left;   
    overflow:auto;
    background:#ffffff;
    }

#header {
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x;
    }

#header .wrap{
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat-x;
    width: 1020px;
    height: 120px;  
    margin:0 auto;  
}

#header .logo{
    margin-top:7px;
    width: 420px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;
}

#header .logo img{
    max-width: 415px;
    max-height:110px;
}

#header .logo .text{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#header .logo h1 a{
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Arial;
    font-size:44px;
    line-height:0.9;

    color:rgba(241,244,245,.7) ;
    font-weight: bold;

    text-shadow:1px 1px rgba(202,216,221,.7),
                2px 2px rgba(202,216,221,.7),
                3px 3px rgba(202,216,221,.7);
    }

#header .logo h1 a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header .right{
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 546px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#header .links {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#header .links ul{
    overflow:auto;
    color:white;
    float:right;
}

#header .links ul li{
    float: left;    
    margin-left:8px;    
}

#header .links ul li a {
    color: #DAE5EC;
    padding-right:8px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#header .twitter{
    background: url("") no-repeat;
    padding-left:55px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif', serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    min-height:40px;
    max-height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header #twitter_update_list{
    color:#cccccc;
    }

#header #twitter_update_list a{
    color: #DAE5EC; 
    }

#subheader{ 
    background: url("images/subheader.png") repeat-x;   
}

#subheader .wrap{
    width: 1020px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    background: url("images/subheader.png") repeat-x;
    height:40px;    
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #7B7B7B; 
    line-height:40px;
}

#subheader ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-right:25px;
}

#subheader .categories{
    width:780px;
    float:left;
}
#subheader .search{
    width:236px;
    float:left;
}

#subheader .search input {
    font: normal 14px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#subheader .search .searchfield {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 7px 6px 7px 8px;
    width: 220px;
    border: solid 1px #bcbbbb;
    outline: none;
    margin-top:4px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#content{
    float: left;
    width: 716px;
    overflow: auto; 
}

#featured-cat{
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 10px 10px 5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #D4D4D4;

}

#featured-cat .cat-title{   
    background:#f6f6f6;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;    
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#featured-cat .box{
    width:220px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#featured-cat .margin-right{
    margin-right:15px;
}

#featured-cat .thumb{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:130px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#featured-cat .date{
    position:absolute;
    background: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 2px 5px 4px 5px;
    top: 20px;
}

#featured-cat .details{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    clear:both;
    padding-top: 8px;   
}

#content .post{
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 10px 10px 5px 0px;
    }
#content  .s_socialbar{
    margin-top:30px; 
    margin-left: -80px; 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    background:#ECF5FA; 
    border-radius:7px;
}

#content  .s_socialbar ul{
    margin:10px 5px 0px 5px;
}
#content  .s_socialbar ul li{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#content  .s_socialbar .fb-like{
    margin:0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

#content .post .postmeta {
    overflow:auto;
    padding:2px;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #777777;
}

#content .post .postmeta .comments{
    float:right; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    background:url(images/comments.png) no-repeat left center; 
    padding-left:20px;  
}

#content .wp-post-image{
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

#content .entry img{
    max-width: 97.5%;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:2px
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    margin:5px 10px 5px 0;
}

#content .thumb-twitter-entry{
    overflow:auto;
    width: 420px;
    float:left;
}

#content .thumb-entry{
    float:left;
    width: 489px;
}

#content .twitter-entry{
    float:left;
    width: 635px;
}

#content .entry{
    overflow:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#content .post-twitter{
    width: 60px;
    float:left;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 5px;
}

#content .wp-caption{
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    padding-top:4px;
    margin:10px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -khtml-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}
#content .wp-caption img{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0 none;
}
#content .wp-caption p.wp-caption-text{
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:17px;
    padding:0 4px 5px;
    margin:0;
}
#content .entry blockquote{
    background: url("images/quote.png") no-repeat;
    font-family: "Georgia", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
        margin: 5px 5px 10px 25px;
        padding-left: 32px;
        padding-top: 3px;
    font-style:italic;
}

#content .entry ul{
    list-style-type:square;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 40px;
}

#content .entry ol{
    list-style-type:decimal;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 40px;
}

#sidebar{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

#sidebar h4{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 24px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

#sidebar .box{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    padding:5px;
}

#sidebar_social{
    overflow:auto;
    margin:10px 0;
}

#sidebar_social a{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 50px 5px 0px;  
   }


#sidebar_social ul{
    overflow:auto;
}

#sidebar_social ul li{
    width:70px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:50px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:auto;  
}

#sidebar .widget_categories{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sidebar .widget_categories h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/tag.png') no-repeat 5px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_categories ul, #footer .widget_categories ul{
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px 5px;
    margin: 5px;    
}

#sidebar .widget_categories ul li, #footer .widget_categories ul li{
    margin-right:8px;
    float: left;    
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#sidebar .widget_categories  ul li a, #footer .widget_categories  ul li a{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    border-right: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    color: #777777;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#sidebar .widget_categories  ul li a:hover,#footer .widget_categories  ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;  
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

#sidebar .widget_archive h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/calendar.png') no-repeat 5px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_archive ul, #sidebar .widget_links ul{
    padding:5px;
}

#sidebar .widget_archive ul li, #sidebar .widget_links ul li{
    padding:3px 0px 3px 12px;
    background:url(images/cat_bullet.png) no-repeat left center;
}

#sidebar .widget_links h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/bookmarks.png') no-repeat 5px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_subscribers{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#sidebar .widget_subscribers .counts{
    margin:15px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#sidebar .widget_subscribers .counts img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#sidebar .widget_subscribers .fb{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left:25px;
}

#sidebar .widget_subscribers .twitter{
    float:left;
}
#sidebar .widget_subscribers .count{    
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#sidebar .widget_subscribers .count a{
    color: #404040 !important;
    }

#sidebar .widget_subscribers .count a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts{ 
    margin-bottom:10px;     
    }

#sidebar .widget_posts ul.tabs {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 24px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #FFF;
    background:url(images/sidebar_posts.png) no-repeat top center;  
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Arial;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li {
    float: left;
    padding-top:3px;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li:hover {
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li.current {   
    color: #333333;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .post_box.visible {
    display: block;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li.recent{ 
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/calendar1.png') no-repeat 5px center;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:65px;
}
#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li.popular{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/heart.png') no-repeat 5px center;
    margin-right:5px;
    width:70px; 
    }

#sidebar .widget_posts .tabs li.comments{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/comments.png') no-repeat 5px center;
    width:80px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .posts-list li{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#sidebar .widget_posts .post_box {
    display: none;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px;
    padding: 5px;
    height:255px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .info{
    float:left;
    width:210px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .meta {
    font-style:italic;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .meta .date{
    float:left;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .meta .cmts{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px; 
    background:url(images/comment.png) no-repeat left center; 
    padding-left:20px; 
    font-style:normal;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts  .posts-list li .title{
    font-weight:bold;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .thumb{
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;   
}

#sidebar .widget_posts   .avatar-42{
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .comment-info{
    float:left;
    width:230px;
}

#sidebar .widget_posts .comment-info p{
    line-height:15px;
}

#sidebar .widget_facebook h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/facebook.png') no-repeat 5px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_facebook{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#sidebar .widget_text h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/about.png') no-repeat 5px center;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#sidebar .widget_text { 
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#footer .widget_text h4{
    background:url('images/about.png') no-repeat 12px center;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#sidebar .widget_ad125{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#sidebar .widget_ad125 h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/star.png') no-repeat 5px center;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#sidebar .widget_ad125 li{
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px;   
}

#sidebar .widget_ad125 li img{
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
}
#footer {
    background: url("images/bg.png") repeat;        
}

#footer .wrap{
    width: 1020px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
    color: #CCCCCC; 
}

#footer .main{
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

#footer  .box{
    float: left;
    width:330px;    
}

#footer .info{
    font-size:12px; 

}

#footer h4{
    padding-left:32px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-shadow:none;
}

#footer a{
    color: #DAE5EC;
}
#footer .widget_text{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#footer .widget_links ul, #footer .widget_archive ul, #footer .widget_categories ul{
    padding:0px 15px;   
}

#footer .widget_links h4{
    background:url('images/bookmarks.png') no-repeat 12px center;
}

#footer .widget_archive h4{
    background:url('images/calendar.png') no-repeat 12px center;
}

#footer .widget_categories h4{
    background:url('images/tag.png') no-repeat 12px center;
}

#footer .widget_links, #footer .widget_archive, #footer .widget_categories, #footer .widget_text{
    float: left;
    width:298px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#footer .widget_links ul li, #footer .widget_archive ul li{
    padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
    background:url(images/u.png) no-repeat left center;
}

#footer .widget_tweets{
    width:298px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
}

#footer .widget_tweets h4.title{
    background:url('images/twitter.png') no-repeat 12px center;
}

#footer .widget_social{
    width:298px;
    float: left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#footer .widget_social h4{
    background:url('images/interact.png') no-repeat 12px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_social h4{
    background:#f6f6f6 url('images/interact.png') no-repeat 5px center;
}

#sidebar .widget_social ul{
    padding:10px 5px;
}

#footer .widget_social ul{
    padding:0px 15px;
}

#footer .widget_social ul li{
    padding: 2px 0 2px 20px;
}

#sidebar .widget_social ul li{
    padding:4px 0px 4px 20px;
}
.widget_social ul li.facebook{
    background:url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.widget_social ul li.twitter{
    background:url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.widget_social ul li.gplus{
    background:url(images/gplus.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.widget_social ul li.rss{
    background:url(images/rss.png) no-repeat left center;
}
.widget_social ul li.contact{
    background:url(images/email.png) no-repeat left center;
}

 #gazpo-socialbar {
    background: #E3EDF4;
    border-color: #E3EDF4;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -65px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    width: 65px;
 }

#respond .cancel-comment-reply{
    float:right;
}
#comments h3, #content .comments h4 {
    margin:10px 0px; 
}

#comments  ol.commentlist { 
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    overflow: visible; 
}

#comments li.comment { 
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

#comments li.comment .comment-body { 
    margin-left: 65px; 
    position: relative; 
    min-height:60px; 
}

#comments li.comment .comment-meta { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    width: 50%; 
}

#comments li.comment .avatar { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -65px; 
    padding: 3px; 
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
}

#comments .comment-awaiting-moderation{
    color: red;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:italic;
}

#comments li.comment p { 
    clear: both;    
}

#comments li.comment cite, li.bypostauthor li.comment cite { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-style: normal; 
    padding-right:10px; 
    margin-right: 8px; 
    float: left;
}

#comments .commentmetadata, .commentmetadata a { 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #999; 
}

#comments .commentmetadata a:hover {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#comments .says { 
    display: none; 
}

#comments .comment-meta { 
    margin: 0 0 10px; 
    line-height: 18px; 
    position: relative; 
}

#comments li.comment .comment-body a.comment-reply-link { 
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0px; 
    padding-right: 10px; 
    font-size: 12px;    
}

#comments .children { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 10px 0 0px 30px; 
}

#comments .children li.comment .comment-body { 
    margin-left: 70px; 
    position: relative; 
    min-height:60px; 
}

#comments .children  li.comment .avatar {
    position: absolute; 
    left: -65px;
}

#respond {
    margin-top:15px;
}

#commentform {
    background: #f6f6f6;    
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:20px 0px;    
}

#commentform .fields-container{
    overflow:auto;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

#commentform  .info{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 250px;
}

#commentform  .info span{
    font-style:italic;
}

#commentform label{
    clear: both;
    color: #667780;
    display: block;    
    line-height: 24px;
}

#commentform input{
    width: 240px;
    border: 1px solid #CAD9E0;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    padding: 8px 3px;
}

#commentform textarea {
    height: 150px;
    width:98%;
    border: 1px solid #CAD9E0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #333333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 6px 3px;
}

#commentform .message{
    float: left;
    width: 410px;
}

#commentform .gazpo-button{
    width: 80px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}

.gazpo-button{
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 14px/100% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 2px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    vertical-align: baseline;   
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #EDEDED) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
    color: #606060; 
}

.gazpo-button:hover {
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#dcdcdc));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fff,  #dcdcdc);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dcdcdc');
}
.gazpo-button:active {
    color: #999;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#fff));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ededed,  #fff);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#ffffff');
}

.pagination {
    clear:both;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 0;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#313031;
}

.pagination span{
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    text-align:center;
}
.pagination a {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #9aafe5;  
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #2e6ab1;
}

.pagination a:hover, .pagination a:active{
    border: 1px solid #2b66a5;
    color: #000;
}

.pagination .current{
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #2e6ab1;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put these  inside another div and make it 1020px wide, secure the position and max/min widths.

```
<div id="wrapper/container">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="subheader"></div>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Or re-make theme using responsive design with grid and nice columns.

Comment: Im using a theme for this. I'm really a novice at css and wordpress coding. Can you please explain better? Where do I put the code you've mentioned? in css, i presume. Anywhere within the css? Also how do I secure the position and max/min widths.